# Angular tree component virtual scrolling is not working

Tags: angular-tree-component

I have taken the files from folder of virtual scroll in my existing project to perform a POC on virtual scrolling.

https://github.com/CirclonGroup/angular-tree-component/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/virtualscroll/virtualscroll.component.ts

There is no virtual scroll enabled with the same code.
[Behavior at my end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/33XuA.png)

If I run the project from github (angular-tree-component) I am getting the scroll.
Reference of the working code:
https://angular2-tree.readme.io/docs/large-trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my code somebody had overridden in overrides.scss the below line:

```css
tree-viewport {
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Removing this line worked for me.